# Export specific rows including CLOB's without DDL

Tags: database, oracle, export

I am looking for the right tool to export specific rows (WHERE condition) of some oracle database tables. There is one column with CLOB Data which can be larger than 4000 characters, therefore exports as "INSERT INTO" statements do not work.

Using `exp` works but also exports the DDL, which gives errors when using `imp` as the Table is already existing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `IGNORE=Y` parameter when importing the dump file.  This tells the import to ignore creation errors.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/exp_imp.htm#sthref2448).